# Saving javafx properties in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, javafx, gson

This time im playing around with the mongodb. I know how to insert documents, updating, json format and so on. Last I created my data holder class with an javafx string property to show the result of queries in a tableview. So the problem is now, if I save the class in mongodb, it saves the property as object with three sub values (property, value, valid). Is there some possibilitie to save it as key:value like a normal string? The problem with the object is, that the query is much more complicated then the key:value thing.

First I create my object, convert it to json with Google gson library and then save it via the document class in the database.

Minimal example: Data Class

```
public class DatabaseEntry {

private String companyName;
private int _id;
private int emploees;
private ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList<Invoice> invoices = new ArrayList();
private StringProperty testString = new SimpleStringProperty();

public DatabaseEntry(String companyName, int emploees, int _id, String test){
    this.companyName=companyName;
    this.emploees=emploees;
    this._id=_id;
    this.testString.setValue(test);
}
```

Main Class;

```
    public class MongoDB {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DatabaseEntry entry = new DatabaseEntry("toolhouse", 18, 16,"Property");
        System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(objToSave));
    }
}
```

The output is:

"testString":{"name":"",
              "value":"Property",
              "valid":false}

Comment: Am I correct in saying that mongodb is slightly irrelevant to the question and the immediate problem you are trying to solve is: "How do I use gson to serialize and deserialize properties from a JavaFX class as key/value json pairs rather than property/value/valid objects?".  Also, even though you haven't mentioned it, I'm guessing ObservableLists will also present similar serialization/deserialization issues for you?  You may wish to add an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this part: "I create my object, convert it to json with Google gson library".

Comment: I added a mcve. Yes you are right that mongodb has nothing to do with the json format saving ... But i want to mention it, because there could be an in build solution or some one had this problem and solved it with some mongodb function.

Comment: Anyone with an solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a [GSON type adapter](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Writing-a-Serializer) to perform a custom serialization and deserialization of the property:

*StringPropertyAdapter.java*

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class StringPropertyAdapter implements
        JsonSerializer<StringProperty>, 
        JsonDeserializer<StringProperty> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(
            StringProperty property, 
            Type type, 
            JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext
    ) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(
                property.getValue()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public StringProperty deserialize(
            JsonElement json, 
            Type type, 
            JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext
    ) throws JsonParseException {
        return new SimpleStringProperty(
                json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString()
        );
    }
}
```

*PropertySerializationTest.java*

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class PropertySerializationTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final DatabaseEntry entry = new DatabaseEntry("toolhouse", 18, 16, "Property");
        final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(StringProperty.class, new StringPropertyAdapter());
        final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

        System.out.println("Serialized Data:");
        String json = gson.toJson(entry);
        System.out.println(json);

        System.out.println("De-serialized/Re-serialized Data:");
        DatabaseEntry rebuiltEntry = gson.fromJson(json, DatabaseEntry.class);
        String rebuiltJson = gson.toJson(rebuiltEntry);
        System.out.println(rebuiltJson);
    }
}
```

*DatabaseEntry.java*

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class DatabaseEntry {

    private String companyName;
    private int _id;
    private int employees;
    private StringProperty testString = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public DatabaseEntry(String companyName, int employees, int _id, String test) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.employees = employees;
        this._id = _id;
        this.testString.setValue(test);
    }
}
```

*Program Output*

```
Serialized Data:
{"companyName":"toolhouse","_id":16,"employees":18,"testString":"Property"}
De-serialized/Re-serialized Data:
{"companyName":"toolhouse","_id":16,"employees":18,"testString":"Property"}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked really nice. Next time i should look deeper in the api ... First i thougt i could handle this with the Externasizable interface but json dont use the java way.